# Not able to pass the values from MVC(Razor) view to JsonResult method in Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I'm having two dropdown lists in my MVC(Razor) view: Country and State.
I'm able to fill both the dropdown's independent of each other.Now i want to fill second dropdown(State) based on the change event of Country's dropdown.

For this I have used JsonResult method in Controller and for this method i'm passing countryID on the Change event of Country from my view inorder to fill my second dropdown state.

**Problem Statement:** The JsonResult method is getting triggered from my view but the CountryId value is not getting passed from view to controller in-order to fill state.

What i'm doing wrong here?

**View:**

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function CountryChange() {

        var url = '@Url.Content("~/MasterConfigGeneral/GetState")';
        var ddlsource = "#CountryID";
        var ddltarget = "#StateID";
        if ($(ddlsource).val() != "") {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.getJSON(url, { countryID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                $(ddltarget).empty();

                $("#StateID").append("<option  value=''>Select State</option>");

                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                    $("#StateID").append("<option value='" + optionData.Value + "'>" + optionData.Text + "</option>");
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#StateID").empty();
            $("#StateID").append("<option value=''>Select State</option>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Dropdown's in my View:**

```
 <div class="cssclass">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.companyModel.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.ddlCountryStateCity.ddlCountry, "Value", "Text"), "Select Country", new { onchange="CountryChange()" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.CountryID)
    </div>

    <div class="cssclass">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.StateID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("stateid",Model.ddlCountryStateCity.ddlState,"Select State")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.StateID)
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

**Country Dropdown:**

```
#region Country
    public DropdownListCountryStateCity FillDropDownListCountry()
    {
        objDropDownCountryStateCity.ddlCountry = (from s in dbEntity.Countries
                                                  select new SelectListItem()
                                                  {
                                                      Text = s.Name,
                                                      Value = s.CountryID

                                                  }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
        return objDropDownCountryStateCity;
    }
    #endregion
```

**State Dropdown:**

```
#region State

    public JsonResult GetState(string countryID)
    {
        JsonResult jsResult = new JsonResult();
        objDropDownCountryStateCity.ddlState = (from csc in dbEntity.CountryStateCities
                                                join c in dbEntity.Countries on csc.CountryID equals c.CountryID
                                                join s in dbEntity.States on csc.StateID equals s.StateID
                                                where csc.CountryID == countryID
                                                select new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = s.Name,
                                                    Value = s.StateID

                                                }).ToList<SelectListItem>();

        jsResult.Data = objDropDownCountryStateCity.ddlState;
        jsResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return jsResult;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that the selected dropdown value is coming correct from the client javascript method CountryChange() ?

Comment: @Thanigainathan :Yes.Even i'm doubting this.Values are getting filled properly in Model.ddlCountryStateCity.ddlCountry. but i'm not sure whether selected value is getting passed to change event "CountryChange()". Any selcted Property we need to set in dropdownlistfor() method for country..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies on how the DropDownListFor helper generates the element.

In your code, it's generating names and ids something like this:

```
<select id="companyModel_CountryID" name="companyModel.CountryID">
    ...
</select>
```

In your javascript the ddlSouce is "#CountryID". Since there's no element with that id, jQuery pass null as data to $.getJSON. That's why the controller method receives nothing.

You have two options:

- Change ddlSource javascript to the proper id (you'll have to see on the source code) OR
- Change the last DropDownListFor helper from

`new { onchange="CountryChange()" }`

to

`new { id = "CountryID", onchange="CountryChange()" }`

IMHO, the last option is the best choice.

Comment: @Denis-Thanks for your suggestion.Now i'm able to get Country value in JsonResult Method.And i'm even getting respective states from the linq query.When i'm returning JsonResult back to view it is not binding with the values for 2nd dropdown even if values are there.What's the reason?

Comment: @Vishal jQuery is case sensitive. The second dropdown is being created with "stateid" as id and jQuery is looking for "StateID". I recommend you refactor your JS to use in your selectors only the variables (ddlsource & ddltarget) or get rid of them and use only hard coded values.

Comment: @Denis-Thanks a lot it solved my problem.Now I'm able to fill second dropdown, based on the changed event of 1st dropdown.